# How to display custom info in MAGE algorithm query results?

Tags: memgraphdb

I'm currently working on a project and I'm developing an algorithm using MAGE. When a bug occurs, the query result exclusively shows the error message and omits the information I've manually entered in the module. Is there a way to ensure that the information inputted in the query structure window is also displayed along with the error message in the query result?

This is my query

```
MATCH()-[r]->() RETURN r;
CALL nuealgo.bsc(3)
```

and the error

```
Query failed
nuealgo.bsc: Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/var/lib/memgraph/internal_modules/nuealgo.py", line 36, in nuealgo.bsc 
B[I[u_id]]. remove(I[u_id])
KeyError: 3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Python Query Module logger to print out what is happening inside the module. The code should be something like:

```
import mgp
@mgp.read_proc
def log(
  context: mgp.ProcCtx,
  data: mgp.Nullable[mgp.Any]
) -> mgp.Record(done=bool):
  # https://memgraph.com/docs/custom-query-modules/python/python-api#logger-objects
  logger = mgp.Logger()
  try:
    ... code ...
  except Exception as e:
    logger.info(str(e)) # or something better
  return mgp.Record(done=True)
```

Or you can try to use the mock [Python API](https://memgraph.com/docs/custom-query-modules/python/mock-python-api).